Initial margin requirement for futures
I am sitting an exam for a certification from the Greek Capital Commission. We have been given multiple choice questions along with their answers in order to prepare ourselves.
I am really confused by a question though.This is the following..
An investor buys 15 future contracts of company AAA. Every contract refers to 100 shares. The initial margin requirement is 12% and the futures' price is 24 euros.
1)How much money should an investor deposit as initial margin if the basis is 3?
The correct answer should be 3.780 euros.
2)What is the role of basis?
3)So far in previous questions in order to calculate the initial margin requirement we were multipying (number of contracts x shares in contracts x initial margin x the spot price at the day of buy). We were completely ignoring the futures' price.

What do you find confusing about it? Which terms, or formulas, or policies, are you not familiar with? If you show what you've done so far, people are more likely to critique that than they are to just give you an answer -- and that will be more useful to you in understanding how to handle this.

Without knowing any of this it is very easy to reverse engineer that 12% * 15 contracts * 100 shares * (24- 3 basis) = 3,780 EUR.
From that one concludes the "basis" is a specific component that separates the futures price to another price (e.g. spot) from which the margin is usually determined.

I have done the reverse engineering. Basis = Spot - Futures Price, so the Spot Price = 27 not 21. If we plug 27 we don't get 3,780 EUR as the answer. This why i am confused keshlam. Basis should be either -3 (which it isn't) or the answer of 3,780 is wrong. Anyone sure about the solution?
